# Inline-block DIV tags are shown below the one with the most content

Tags: html, css

For my school project (and for my personal needs), I'm starting my own personal site.

I have 4 inline-block DIVs. The first one has some content in it, and all the others are empty except for a heading.

The empty ones are "pushed", and are vertically aligned towards the bottom of the one WITH the content. Example on the site @ http://rickyyoder.x10.mx.

Is there something I can do that doesn't involve using floats to achieve this?
And if I have to use floats, what exactly do I do? I tried floating each "left", and giving a left margin of 20% (the width of each section), and they *still* stacked on top of each other.

Please help me understand. Thank you!

Edit: The current CSS code for each content DIV:

```
   #c.section-split div.section{
        display:inline-block;
        width:20%;
        max-width:20%;
        margin-right:2%;
        position:relative;
        background:#aaa;
        border-top-left-radius:4px;
        border-top-right-radius:4px;
    }
```

Comment: Post some code here and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: It's look good on your site

Comment: I just fixed it thanks to Paulie_D's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your div's css

```
vertical-align:top
```

Comment: I thought vertical-align only worked on table cells (or I guess that's just "middle"). It worked perfectly! Thank you! I'll accept your answer in the next 7 minutes. :/